# Getting started with Python on Emacs

Tags: python, macos, emacs, terminal

I am familiar with python but completely new to Emacs, and I want to start using the latter for coding. In Emacs, I ran

```
M-x python-mode
```

And I get

```
Loading python...                                                                                                                
Loading easymenu...done                                                                                                          
Loading python...done
```

And then nothing happens. It doesn't freeze, it doesn't go to python mode...it just doesn't change. Could someone please help me fix this problem? I am running Emacs from the Mavericks terminal.

Comment: Does the mode line at the bottom of the window not then display "(Python)" as the major mode for that buffer? Likewise, typing `C-h m` (or `M-x describe-mode`) in that buffer should clearly display Python mode as the major mode. Emacs should automatically use `python-mode` when you visit a python file, however -- you wouldn't commonly need to call the mode manually.

Comment: You might also investigate third-party libraries like [elpy](http://elpy.readthedocs.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Emacs, `foo-mode` generally sets the mode of the current buffer to `foo`. In your case, you were setting the current buffer to `python-mode`, which doesn't directly do anything unless you're looking at Python code.

The [Python Programming in Emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs) wiki page is a bit... sprawling... but it has lots of good information. Before that, I'd suggest going through the Emacs tutorial (hit `C-h t` to launch it) to learn more about Emacs's underlying principles. That's going to save you a *lot* of confusion later.